# Use JavaScript script as function to update resource parameter?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, youtube-api

When I create a new video resource I want to update the `length` parameter with data from a JavaScript script. These are all the parameters in my video resource:

```
 create_table "videos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.text     "name"
    t.integer  "playcount"
    t.integer  "length"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "stream_id"
    t.string   "video_id"
    t.string   "vidstring"
  end
```

The `vidstring` parameter is created in a method in the model:

```
vidstring = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + video_id + "?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=youtubeFeedCallback&prettyprint=true"
```

This is the code I need to use to get the data. Where should this code be stored?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function youtubeFeedCallback(json){
    document.write(json["data"]["title"]);
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src= <%= video.vidstring %> >

</script>
```

How can I extract `(json["data"]["title"])` from this script and store it in the `"length"` parameter when I create a new video resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: make a more descriptive question. Anyway, it seems youtube answers with raw json (example: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Dy9rGCS4ZHw?v=2&alt=jsonc). You probably want data[duration] instead.

As @Puhlze says, it's better to do this on the server side with a callback. There's [a ruby gem for consuming the YT api](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) but I think for this simple task this will suffice:

```
require 'open-uri'
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # more stuff omitted
  before_save :get_youtube_video_duration

  def get_yotube_video_duration
    # duration are seconds it seems
    duration = JSON.parse(
      open("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{self.video_id}?v=2&alt=jsonc").read
    )['data']['duration']
    self.length = duration
  end
  #...
```

Check [rails callbacks](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=rails+callbacks&oq=rails+callbacks&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i59.1832j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I altered this to be called from the create method in my controller. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this youtube data in rails, but you're collecting it in a rendered view.

If you want to query youtube for data to add to a rails model you should look into using the YouTube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) so that you can collect this data in rails, rather than on the client / web browser.